# MsgBox not displayed on 1st click after changing content in textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am trying to learn by creating this basic form. where the user is asked a password and username
currently both are text field and insecure.
the problem is that whenever i change any of the 2 fields the 1st click does not work.
the code works fine from 2nd click.

edit- there is no problem till the user and password are wrong.

here is the snippet

```
Private Sub BtnLogIn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLogIn.Click
    If (TxtUsername.Text = "shikhar" And TxtPassword.Text = "pass") Then
        'goto next screen & remove message box'
        MsgBox("correct Username or Password", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Information, "login Completed")
    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect Username or Password", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly + MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "login error")

    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

this is the overall file-

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Login
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.lblUsername = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.lblPassword = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.TxtUsername = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.TxtPassword = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.BtnLogIn = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'lblUsername
    '
    Me.lblUsername.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblUsername.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(69, 84)
    Me.lblUsername.Name = "lblUsername"
    Me.lblUsername.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(55, 13)
    Me.lblUsername.TabIndex = 0
    Me.lblUsername.Text = "Username"
    '
    'lblPassword
    '
    Me.lblPassword.AutoSize = True
    Me.lblPassword.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(69, 130)
    Me.lblPassword.Name = "lblPassword"
    Me.lblPassword.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(53, 13)
    Me.lblPassword.TabIndex = 1
    Me.lblPassword.Text = "Password"
    '
    'TxtUsername
    '
    Me.TxtUsername.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(178, 77)
    Me.TxtUsername.Name = "TxtUsername"
    Me.TxtUsername.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(199, 20)
    Me.TxtUsername.TabIndex = 2
    '
    'TxtPassword
    '
    Me.TxtPassword.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(178, 123)
    Me.TxtPassword.Name = "TxtPassword"
    Me.TxtPassword.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(198, 20)
    Me.TxtPassword.TabIndex = 3
    '
    'BtnLogIn
    '
    Me.BtnLogIn.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(181, 172)
    Me.BtnLogIn.Name = "BtnLogIn"
    Me.BtnLogIn.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(164, 45)
    Me.BtnLogIn.TabIndex = 4
    Me.BtnLogIn.Text = "Log In"
    Me.BtnLogIn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'Login
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(474, 261)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.BtnLogIn)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TxtPassword)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TxtUsername)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblPassword)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.lblUsername)
    Me.Name = "Login"
    Me.Text = "Login"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub
Friend WithEvents lblUsername As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents lblPassword As System.Windows.Forms.Label
Friend WithEvents TxtUsername As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents TxtPassword As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
Friend WithEvents BtnLogIn As System.Windows.Forms.Button
End Class
```

Comment: on `BtnLogIn_click` what values that your getting in `TxtUsername.Text` and `TxtPassword.Text`

Comment: see edit- it doesn't matter. as soon as any text is changed the 1st click after that is useless

Comment: i dont understand you , please show your form's screen shots at the runtime

Comment: And where is the problem now? The code works.

Comment: i does work but shows erratic behavior, sometimes the first click does nothing at all, then click again and boom "Perfect!"

Comment: Most likely a focus issue?

Comment: i have no clue at all... help me solve!! please

Comment: I have copied and pasted that code, works fine for me.. try creating a new form and copy in that code... remember to change the form name in the designer in the copied code else it will error